# How can i hide a specific error messages in windows 10 with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to hide a specific event error message for example "has stopped working" in windows 10 with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

In the registry, there is **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting** and it has a property called **DontShowUI** which you want to change from 0 to 1

In PowerShell that would be:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" -Name "DontShowUI" -Value 1
```

You can use Get-ItemProperty with the same syntax to check if the changes were applied.

Comment: Won't this hide **all** error messages, not just the specific one?

Comment: @Theo This is for all the "has stopped working" errors. I'm not sure which specific message OP meant,

Comment: Thank's for the response... In my case there is a .exe who brings the error "has stopped working". As a solution I created a small script, that changes the value to 1 when the programm is active and then changes the value to 0 when the programm finished.